# JSONArray Manipulation

Tags: java, json, json-simple

in my code i created a JSONArray object.And adding two JSONObjects to the JSONArray object.I am using json-simple-1.1.jar.My code is

```
package jsonjava;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
public class JsonJava {
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    JSONArray ja=new JSONArray();
    JSONObject jo=new JSONObject();
    jo.put("name","prem");
    jo.put("id", 2012103575);
    jo.put("Age",20);
    ja.add(jo);
    JSONObject jo1=new JSONObject();
    jo1.put("name","prem");
    jo1.put("id", 2012103575);
    jo1.put("Age",21);
    ja.add(jo1);
    for(int i=0;i<ja.size();i++)
      System.out.println(ja.get(i));
}
```

My Question is how to get the Age value from second object("jo1") from JSONArray object ("ja").I tried ja.get(1).get("Age").It doesn't work.Can any one suggest idea.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using json-simple jar. There is no separate method to get JSONObject.

First You need to cast that object to JSONObject, then you can do further processing.

```
for(int i=0;i<ja.size();i++){
    JSONObject json=(JSONObject) ja.get(i);
    System.out.println(json.get("Age"));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try Following:

```
for(int i=0;i<ja.size();i++)
      System.out.println(ja.getJSONObject(i).get("Age"));
```

Comment: ja.getJSONObject() not available in my jar..can you say which json jar you are using.

Comment: Here's the one which I am using http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjsonlib24jdk15jar.htm